# Create a workflow to add a hyperlink based of the creation of a list or library?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation, hyperlink

I've received an odd request from our Team Lead.  He wants to know if it is possible when someone adds a list or library to a site a Links List is automatically updated with that information (list/library title and hyperlink and description).  I pointed him to the Site Content page but he really wants a link list.  Is there a way to do this using a workflow?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible to do what you want with a workflow. Site workflows are manually started and would not be able to retrieve the information you are wanting in order to create a list, same with a list workflow. You would have no way to trigger it automatically if a list or library was added.

I'd suggest looking into using the Content Search web part. Create a query that identifies only the list and document titles then create a custom display template that retrieves the Title, Link to List/Library, and the Description. You can then display the search results in order of newest to oldest.

A couple links I found that will give you a starting point:

[SE: How to get the list name on a content search web part display template](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117279/how-to-get-the-list-name-on-a-content-search-webpart-displaytemplate)

[Retrieving the list or library name of a search result in display templates](https://www.eliostruyf.com/retrieving-list-library-name-search-result-display-templates/)

[Adding a link to the search result list or library into your display template](https://www.eliostruyf.com/adding-link-search-result-list-library-display-template/)